# Draw a rectangular bounding box around a person in an image

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, matlab-cvst, bounding-box

I want to make a bounding box around a person in an image.  I tried different methods but I couldn't get the solution that I want.

Here's the image I am using:

[image]

Here's the code I have written so far:

```
bw = im2bw(test, graythresh(test));    
bw2 = imfill(bw,'holes');  
imshow(bw2);  

figure;  
L = bwlabel(bw2);  
imshow(label2rgb(L, @jet, [.7 .7 .7]))  

figure;  
imshow(I1);  
R = regionprops(L, 'BoundingBox');  
rectangle('Position', R(1).BoundingBox);
```

Comment: Your problem isn't drawing the bounding box - it's locating the person inside the image.  If you don't do this properly, then there's no way for you to draw this bounding box properly.

Comment: Thanks rayryeng for your suggestion. Is there any way to locate a person inside first?

Comment: Could you upload the original image without the red bounding box?

Comment: here is the link for original image
[link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/w68depnntr3cg03/test.tif?dl=0)

Comment: Original image
[link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/w68depnntr3cg03/test.tif?dl=0)

Comment: OK, give me a moment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem actually isn't drawing the bounding box - it's locating the person inside the image, which you haven't quite done properly.  If you don't do this correctly, then you won't be able place the correct bounding box around the person.  This is what I have done to locate the person in the image, then drawing a bounding box around this person.  This is assuming that your image is stored in `im`:

1. Notice that the intensity distribution of the person is darker than most of the scene.  As such, I'm going to threshold the image by choosing any pixels less than intensity 65 to be white while the other pixels black.
2. I clear any white pixels that surround the image border
3. I perform a `regionprops` call extracting the `BoundingBox` and `Area` properties.
4. I search through all of the areas and find the `BoundingBox` with the largest `Area`.
5. I use this `BoundingBox` and draw it on our image.

Therefore:

```
%// Step #1
im_thresh = im < 65;

%// Step #2
im_thresh2 = imclearborder(im_thresh);

%// Step #3
rp = regionprops(im_thresh2, 'BoundingBox', 'Area');

%// Step #4
area = [rp.Area].';
[~,ind] = max(area);
bb = rp(ind).BoundingBox;

%// Step #5
imshow(im);
rectangle('Position', bb, 'EdgeColor', 'red');
```

---

This is what we get:

[image]

Bear in mind that this isn't perfect.  You may have to play around with the threshold to get a more accurate bounding box, but this should be enough for you to start with.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks rayryeng, when i run the code it give me error in step#4
Undefined variable "A" or class "A".

Comment: @AadnanFarooqA - sorry typo. let me fix

Comment: @AadnanFarooqA - Fixed.  Run it again and try

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `vision.PeopleDetector` in the Computer Vision System Toolbox:

```
im = imread('bnJzI.png');
detector = vision.PeopleDetector('ClassificationModel', 'UprightPeople_96x48', 'ClassificationThreshold', 2.5);
bbox = step(detector, im);
im2 = insertObjectAnnotation(im, 'rectangle', bbox, 'person');
imshow(im2);
```

[image]